# Class library reference problem

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

I am building a class library and using its default namespace as "System". There suppose I am creating a generic data structure say PriorityQueue and putting it under System.Collections.Generic namespace.

Now when I am referencing that library from another project, I can't see PriorityQueue under "System.Collections.Generic" namespace anymore. Though the library is referenced in that project I can not access any of the classes in it.

My question was mscorlib and System.dll share similar namespaces, but still classes from both the assembly is accessible, but why can't mine? If I put a public class under System.Collections.Generic namespace in my class library and refer that library in a project and use a statement like "using System.Collections.Generic", still why I can't access my class there?

This was an experimentation I did, I know using System namespace is not encouraged in custom class library, but I want to know the reason behind why I can't access my class in this special case?

Please someone shed some light on it.

PS: Last time I asked similar question but put it wrongly, so people got misunderstood and I didn't get my answer. This time I am trying to put it correctly as far as I can. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Does it work fine if you try and put your class under a custom namespace?

Comment: yes ofcourse. As I told I was doing some experiments on this idea.

Comment: What's the name of the project output DLL?

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of his other question. He didn't like the answers he got: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032884/class-library-reference-problem.

Comment: @John I have mentioned in PS already, that I put the question wrongly, that's why I got my answer wrongly ..

Comment: I must be missing something because this worked for me.  I added a new 3.5 C# console project and a new class library project to the same solution.  Default namespace and assembly name on the library was "System.Collections.Generic".  I added a class in the library called "Class1".  I added a reference to the libary to the console app and I was able to create an instance of my "System.Collections.Generic.Class1" class.

Still not a recommended practice, but I was able to do it.

Comment: @Anindya: that's not why you got the answers you did. It's because an experiment must have some value, and yours would only show you how to do something very bad and very stupid.

Comment: @John thanks for your comments, by the way I got my answer, thanks to chibacity for his time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to arise when you use a "Project Reference" rather than an "Assembly Reference".

Use an "assembly Reference".

This is such a bad idea that I am reluctant to delve into the underlying reasons.

**Update**

I am guessing that when you use a project reference (from your System namespace project), the issue arises as the build does not know that it should resolve the dependency from your referenced project, but instead it attempts to resolve it from one of the **assemblies** that is already referenced i.e. System.dll. It obviously does not exist in System.dll. If you add a direct reference to a built version of your dll, the build will be able to resolve it.

Comment: As I commented on your other question, please reflect on what would happen if everyone tried to attempt to do what you are doing - chaos. Microsoft can use this technique because they are doing it with their **own**  namespace. The "System" namespace is not yours. Please use your own namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested out some code, and I can extend the System namespace in my own project and then call the new classes from some other project in the same solution. I don't know why are you not able to do it.